# It seems that the je is not working

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to make a simple program which lets me choose if I want to input a word or a number. It seems that the `je` is not working.
I'm just a beginner at TASM so please mind correcting me if there's more than one mistake in the code.

```
.model small
.stack 64h
.data

msg1    db      "Input 1 for word, 2 for number", 13, 10, "$"
fw      db      "Input word", 13, 10, "$"
fn      db      "Input number", 13, 10, "$"
msg2    db      "HEY", 13, 10, "$"
input   db  10  dup ("$")
nl  db  13, 10, "$"

.code
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset msg1
int 21h

mov byte ptr input, 10
mov dx, offset input
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset nl
int 21h 

lea si, input

check:
mov al, [si]
cmp al, 1
je w

n:  
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset fn
int 21h 
jmp exit

w:  
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset fw
int 21h
jmp exit


exit:   
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

end
```

Comment: When you use [int 21h/ah=0eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm) to get input from the user, the characters they entered start at the buffer+2 (buffer+1 is the number of characters entered). So you'll need `mov al, [si+2]` to access the first keystroke rather than `mov al, [si]`. Since you are comparing ascii characters you want to compare against ASCII character `'1'` rather than the value 1. Change `cmp al, 1` to `cmp al, '1'`

Comment: I recommend learning to use Turbo Debugger if you are using TASM. You can step through the instructions and watch what happens to registers and memory.

Comment: @MichaelPetch There's a typo in the function number in your comment. The link itself is correct though.

Comment: @Fifoernik : yeah, I saw it after thanks. Should have read `When you use int 21h/ah=0ah` instead of `When you use int 21h/ah=0eh`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> input   db  10  dup ("$")
> nl  db  13, 10, "$"
> ...
> mov byte ptr input, 10
> mov dx, offset input
> mov ah, 0ah
> int 21h
> ```

You've given DOS a 10-byte inputbuffer (`input db 10 dup ("$")`). If you insist on setting the first byte at 10 (`mov byte ptr input, 10`), then this buffer is not long enough! If ever the user at the keyboard types a 9th character, DOS will overwrite the byte at the label *nl*, thereby destroying your program.

For the BufferedInput function 0Ah, DOS is expecting from you a pointer (in `DX`) to a buffer that has in its 1st byte the length of the storage space that starts at the 3rd byte.
In the 2nd byte, that you should put at zero, will DOS return to you the count of characters that will have been stored in the storage space.
From the fact that DOS always appends a carriage return to these characters in the storage space, comes that, if you specify the length as **10** (in the 1st byte), the user can input at most **9** characters.

You can correct your code by writing:

```
input   db  12  dup (0)
...
mov word ptr input, 10     ; First byte 10, second byte 0
mov dx, offset input
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

But wait, since your input is actually looking for a single character, you could write instead:

```
input   db  80  dup (0)
...
mov word ptr input, 2      ; First byte 2, second byte 0
mov dx, offset input
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h
```

With the **2** you're telling DOS that the storage space has room for a single character of input followed by the mandatory carriage return. Your code doesn't need more than that!
Also see that you can define a large *input* structure (`input db 80 dup (0)`) yet use just a small portion of it (`mov word ptr input, 2`) depending on what your program needs.

---

> ```
> lea si, input
> check:
> mov al, [si]
> cmp al, 1
> je w
> ```

From the explanation above follows that to check for the first/only character you need to look at the 3rd byte:

```
    lea si, input
check:
    mov al, [si+2]
```

And because the input is composed of characters, you will have to compare with the **character "1"** and not the **number 1**:

```
    lea si, input
check:
    mov al, [si+2]
    cmp al, '1'
    je  w
```

The same but smaller:

```
    cmp byte ptr [input + 2], '1'
    je  w
```

---

The DOS TerminateWithExitcode function 4Ch, expects an exitcode in the `AL` register. Kindly provide one and write `mov ax, 4C00h`. An exitcode of 0 signals a *normal termination*.

```
exit:   
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
```